# Send data from java servlet (server side) to a websocket chat

Tags: servlets, websocket

I have created a web application with java servlets and jsp. 
Now I have another web application, that is just a simple websocket chat. Both run on tomcat 8 and JDK 8. I have also a simple html client, that can send data, provided by user input, to the websocket chat.

The url is something like the following:  `ws://myWebsocketUrl.com/websocket/chat`

But how do I send automatically data from a servlet (server side) to a websocket URL?
Every time a specific servlet is called (page visited by a user), I would like automatically to send a message to the websocket chat (the other web application).

I see a lot of stuff where you send data from a html client, a simple java desktop client, but I can't find anything about sending data from a servlet to websocket chat.

Any good libraries or code snippets available?